# Unable to add MMS Intent with sms_body and address in Sony phones

Tags: android, android-intent, sony, sony-xperia, android-mms

This code works fine in other phones but it does not add **sms_body** and **address** in Sony Phones, I have tested it in Xperia Z and Xperia M4.

```
    Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "SMS_TEXT");
    mmsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:")); // This ensures only SMS apps respond
    mmsIntent.putExtra("address", "123456789");
    mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    mmsIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(mmsIntent);
```